# How to create a view with design like datetimepicker (>4.0)in android

Tags: android, android-layout, datetimepicker

I need to create a view with design like `DateTimepicker` in Android

Something like:

Text1

---

Text2

---

Text3

How can I achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use a Custom ScrollView. Or maybe use directly NumberPicker ?

Comment: Thanks....i didn't know there was control named NumberPicker ..Thanks.
I refereed after your comment.
stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings